# Reference request- Shock development problem for the compressible Euler equation in 1D

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I was wondering if there is any good reference discussing the shock development problem for Euler in 1D? Something in the spirit of Christodoulou's work on the same for higher dimension.

I am interested in the quantitative behavior of the solution to the Euler equation as the shock strength increases starting from when the characteristics first collide. Any help will be appreciated.